# Google Play authentication required error

Tags: application-autoupdate

I'm using Android on a Samsung S3. I was initially trying to upgrade WorldMate, but was getting authentication errors. Then I tried to purchase something via Google play, and was given an authentication required error.

I have removed my Google account and re-added it, deleted updates and tried to stop apps being updated automatically but they do no matter what setting I use. I have created a new account and tried via that, but no luck.

How can I stop apps being updated? Is there a service I can stop and put on manual?
Or is there another way to purchase apps/music? All I want  to do is upgrade WorldMate but their support staff have been useless so far...

Comment: I'm confused. What does stopping other updates have to do with updating this one app? What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better inform it to the Google Play store support.

1. Go to this page:- https://support.google.com/googleplay/?hl=en
2. Then click top right "Contact US" button.
3. Follow its on screen instructions.